# Join 2 different tables in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

There are two tables TableA & TableB which has to be merged and shown.
for e.g.,

```
Table A has columnA, columnB 
Table B has column1, column2, column3
```

I want to merge / join these two table and resultant should be

```
columnA, columnB, column1, column2, column3
```

Please help me how can i form the query? Is it possible to use join or union queries?

Comment: you are give primary key and foreign key means any column same to both table?

Comment: Nope both primary key are different.

Comment: select * from TableA,TableB

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya if i have 3 different tables then how would be the query?

Comment: any table but you add table for example: select * from TableA,TableB,TableC,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like,

```
 select * from TableA join TableB
```

It will merge both table like you want and resultant table have `n x m` records. n is number of records in `TableA` and m is number of records in `TableB`